# isSelected() test passes even if checkbox is not checked(selected) using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, checkbox, checked

I have the following element:

```
<input id="InventoryTrackingAllowOutOfStockPurchases" name="allowOutOfStockPurchases" type="checkbox" class="Polaris-Checkbox__Input_30ock" aria-invalid="false" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" value="">
```

I use the following code in order to check if the checkbox is checked:

```
 WebElement sellWithoutStock = driver.findElement(By.name("allowOutOfStockPurchases"));
 sellWithoutStock.isSelected();
```

The thing is that I run the test when the checkbox is unchecked but still the test passes. By running the test I just want to confirm whether the checkbox is checked or not. Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

### [isSelected](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isSelected())

```
boolean isSelected()
```

Determines if the desired element is selected or not. This operation only applies to `<input>` elements such as checkboxes, options in a select and radio buttons. It returns *`True`* if the element is currently selected or checked, false otherwise.

So essentially you need to probe the *`boolean`* value returned through `isSelected()` as follows:

```
if (driver.findElement(By.name("allowOutOfStockPurchases")).isSelected()) {
  System.out.println("pass");
} else {
  System.out.println("fail");
}
```